# Python regex search and identify the first occurence

Tags: python, regex-group

I have a sql string and I need to identify the first occurrence of the database and table name from the sql.

```
sql = 'select col1, col2, "base" as db_name, "employee" as table_name from base.employee where id is not NULL union select col1, col2, "base" as db_name, "employee" as table_name from base.employee where ts is not NULL'

result_dbname = re.search(',?"(.*)as db_name', sql)

db_name = result_dbname.group(1).replace("\"", "")

print(db_name)
```

```
Expected result
base
```

```
Actual Result
base as db_name, employee as table_name from base.employee where id is not NULL union select col1, col2, base
```

I would like to capture only the first occurrence

Comment: You wanted to find `the first occurrence of the database and table name`, do you want only the database name if both exists? Also your attempt was searching for `db_name`, isn't it the column name (so obviously wrong)?

Comment: I wanted the first occurrence of database and table name. I gave the example for database name so I can build on top of it to get the table name. In this case I want "base" and "employee" as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use match group:

```
m = re.match(".*(\".*\") as db_name, (\".*\") as table_name.*", sql)
m.groups()
# ('"base"', '"employee"')
```

Then you can strip the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not super pretty, but you could use:

```py
re.findall(',?"\w+" as db_name', sql)[0].split('"')[1]
```

This just splits the string into three strings:

```py
>>> '"base" as db_name'.split('"')
['', 'base', ' as db_name']
```

So you just take the first index which in this case is `base`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first occurrence, you can start with a non greedy quantifier.

Then use 2 capture groups with a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to not cross matching the double quotes, and just capture what is in between the double quotes.

```
^.*?"([^"]*)" as db_name, "([^"]*)" as table_name\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AhepRf/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/n8QpSw)

```
import re

pattern = r'^.*?"([^"]*)" as db_name, "([^"]*)" as table_name\b'
s = "select col1, col2, \"base\" as db_name, \"employee\" as table_name from base.employee where id is not NULL union select col1, col2, \"base\" as db_name, \"employee\" as table_name from base.employee where ts is not NULL"
m = re.match(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.groups())
```

Output

```
('base', 'employee')
```